# document.open removes all window listeners

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I'm writing a Chrome extension. It's used for recording users' behavior on browsing web pages. It does that by adding event listeners to customers' web pages, using Chrome `content script`.

Code in `content script` looks like:

```
var recordingEvents = ['click', 'input', 'change'];
recordingEvents.forEach(function (e) {
    window.addEventListener(e, handler, true);
});
```

Example of custom page:

```
<script>
function reload() {
    var ifrw = document.getElementById("iframeResult").contentWindow;
    ifrw.document.open();
    ifrw.document.write("<div>abc</div>");  
    ifrw.document.close();
}
</script>
<body>
<input type="submit" onclick="reload();" value="Reload" />
<iframe id="iframeResult"></iframe>
</body>
```

It uses `document.open`, `document.write` to rewrite content of iframe.

Here is the question. My event listeners are attached to `window` object. And `document.open` removes all its event listeners. Like picture below shows.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid `document.open` removing event listeners? Or to observe `document.open`, so I can manually re-add listeners after it?

Comment: Don't call `document.open`.

Comment: I'm writing a Chrome extension, to add event listeners to custom web pages. So I'm not able to determine whether custom uses document.write() or not.

Comment: Why not simply rewrite the content of the iframe on-load or use `window.setTimeout` with `document.write`?

Comment: Could you please read the question again? The web page is not written by me. It's **customers'** pages.

Comment: This is confusing. It's actually not very clear in the question. My comment makes 2 for 2 with misunderstandings.

Comment: It was not clear at all that `document.open` was being called on the customers' page until your last edit. Now I'm left wondering what part of anything is the code you tried to make work, and what is it supposed to do exactly?

Comment: I re-edit the question, please see if it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I've found this issue trying to solve exactly the same problem.

Here is a spec  https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-document-open that says that on `document.open` current document is destroyed and replaced with a fresh one. I had a hope that some event's like "load" are still preserved, no luck.
Here is my detection code:

```
const testEventName = 'TestEvent';
let tm;

function onTestEvent() {
    clearTimeout(tm);
}

function listenToTestEvent() {
    document.addEventListener(testEventName, onTestEvent);
}

listenToTestEvent();

function onLostEvents() {
    console.log('events are lost');
    listenToTestEvent();
    // DO THING HERE
}


function checkIfEventsAreLost() {
    document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(testEventName));
    tm = setTimeout(onLostEvents);
}

new MutationObserver(checkIfEventsAreLost).observe(document, { childList: true });
```

When document is recreated its `childList` is changed(new `documentElement`node), this is the best trigger I've thought of to detect document replacement.

Note that even listeners fire before `setTimeout(..., 0)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a detailed explanation of why [@Viller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41205013/1714951) works. I'm making this a new answer as it didn't fit into a comment

The `TestEvent` event is a special event that monitors when the events that were previously setup in a document are removed.

In particular, this accounts for the case of `document.open`, which removes all listeners not only from the document but also from the window.

The general idea is to setup a listener for a custom event called `TestEvent`, which clears a timeout. Such timeout is setup only when the document mutates and is triggered by a mutation observer.

Since the timeout schedules the operation to happen at least during the next tick of the event loop, such timeout can be cleared before that, avoiding the execution of its callback all together. And, since the `TestEvent` event handler clears that timeout, the fact that the timeout is cleared implies that the listener is still attached. On the other hand, if the timeout is not cleared before the next tick, the would signify the events were removed and a new "setup" is needed.

Answer (score 1):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/open):

> The Document.open() method [...] come(s) with some side effects. For example:
> All event listeners currently registered on the document, nodes inside
> the document, or the document's window are removed.

Below I provide a module (`onGlobalListenerRemoval`) where one can easily register some callback functions to get notified whenever listeners get cleared. This uses the same working principle as the code in [Viller's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41205013/1714951) answer.

**Usage principle:**

```
onGlobalListenerRemoval.addListener(() => {
  alert("All event listeners got removed!")
});
```

**Module code:**

```
const onGlobalListenerRemoval = (() => {
  const callbacks = new Set();
  const eventName = "listenerStillAttached";

  window.addEventListener(eventName, _handleListenerStillAttached);

  new MutationObserver((entries) => {
    const documentReplaced = entries.some(entry =>
      Array.from(entry.addedNodes).includes(document.documentElement)
    );
    if (documentReplaced) {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(_handleListenerDetached);
      window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(eventName, {detail: timeoutId}));
    }
  }).observe(document, { childList: true });

  function _handleListenerDetached() {
    // reattach event listener
    window.addEventListener(eventName, _handleListenerStillAttached);
    // run registered callbacks
    callbacks.forEach((callback) => callback());
  }

  function _handleListenerStillAttached(event) {
    clearTimeout(event.detail);
  }

  return  {
    addListener: c => void callbacks.add(c),
    hasListener: c =>  callbacks.has(c),
    removeListener: c => callbacks.delete(c)
  }
})();
```